# how to dropdown menu dependent photo paste vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table A with dropdowns, and based on their choice, itll make a change to another table B. I then take table B, turn it into a picture, and paste it next to table A. There are multiple problems. When I remove the section about deleting shapes, It doesnt paste where I want it to, actually it posts next to the dropdown that was just selected. There is also the problem that when there are other pictures/buttons in the sheet, it enlarges them. When I do have the deletion part, it deletes every picture and button. Any idea whats the problem?  Here is the code I am using

```
Sub pastePic()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim i As Integer, intCount As Long
Dim destRng As Range

Set Sheet1 = Sheets("NameOfSheet1")
Set Sheet2 = Sheets("NameOfSheet2")

Sheet1.Range("A1:E12").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

With Sheet2
intCount = .Shapes.Count
   For i = intCount To 1 Step -1 
      With .Shapes.Item(i)
         If .Name <> "Picture" Then 
             .Delete
         End If
      End With
   Next i

  .Paste
  Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
  Set shp.Name = "Picture"
  Set destRng = Me.Range("A14")

  With shp
     .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
     .Top =
     .Left
     .Width
     .Height
  
End With
```

I call this sub in Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Select Case Target.Address
    Case Range("A2").Offset(0).Adress
        Call OtherSub
        Call pastePic
    Case Range("A10")...
```

Comment: Is the code situated in a standard module or (most probably) in a sheet code module? If in a sheet code module, then `Me.Range("A14")` references that sheet where the code exists. Then, this `destRng` range is not used anywhere. You do not set the Top, Left, Width etc. at all in the code you show. So, the picture is not handled at all according to what your question states. Please, edit your question and show us all your code. Otherwise, we cannot understand what is wrong in it, I am afraid

Comment: Yes, this is in the sheet code and this is all the code in this sub. Unfortunately I cant post all the code for this sheet, its very very long.  What should I replace `Me.Range` with?

Comment: I have no idea about `Me.Range("A14")` should be... **You should know it**.